# how to get mouse position in windows and auto-click somewhere

Tags: c#

I want to write a program in C# like Ghost-Mouse or auto-clicker. It will find the mouse location in windows and click there as i instructed. The question is, What code should I write to find specific mouse x and y locations and click globally. Can I get a sample code please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

get position by

```
MousePosition.X
   MousePosition.Y
```

example:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y));
    }
```

Comment: does it get if only mouse is inside of the form's boundary? What if the user changes the window with alt + tab?